# SMPP - Receiving Messages

Tags: c#, smpp

I am new to SMPP and I'm using JamatechSMPP (an opensource .NET library for SMPP) to connect to a SMSC. I'm successfully able to send messages however I'm unable to receive. Jamatech help documents say that an event called "client_MessageReceived" will be raised when a message is received but the receiving is failing and I am not sure how I can raise that event when a message is received.

```
class UTSystem 
{
    private static SmppClient client;

UTSystem() 
{
    client = new SmppClient();
}

public static SmppClient ConnectToSMSC() 
{
    try 
    {
        client.Shutdown();

        SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
        properties.SystemID = "xxxxxxxx";
        properties.Password = "xxxxxxx";
        properties.Port = xxxx; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = "xxxxxxxxxxx"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = "SMPP";
        properties.DefaultServiceType = ServiceType.CELLULAR_MESSAGING;
        properties.AddressNpi = NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
        properties.AddressTon = TypeOfNumber.Unknown;

        client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;

        client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;

        //Start smpp client
        client.ForceConnect();

        return client;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return client;
    }
}

public static void ReceiveSMS() 
{
    try 
    {
        ConnectToSMSC();

        client.MessageReceived += new EventHandler < MessageEventArgs > (client_MessageReceived);

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {}
}

static public void client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) 
{
    //The event argument e contains more information about the received message

    TextMessage textMsg = e.ShortMessage as TextMessage; //This is the received text message

    int res = SaveMsg(textMsg.SourceAddress.ToString(), textMsg.Text.ToString());
}
```

Comment: please make sure your code is well indented - it makes it easier to read, and so easier for us to help.

Comment: how do you know the receiving is failing? Are you sure the event isn't raised? how did you initialize the client object?

Comment: Hi elyashiv. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I know receiving is failing because when I message via the phone it doesn't go through, and I receive a message saying "Sending Failed". Here is how I am initializing the client object: private static SmppClient client = new SmppClient();

        UTLSystem()
        {
            client = new SmppClient();
        }

Comment: I am trying to edit my question and add more code to it as you require.

Comment: eliyashiv, I have added the required code in my question. Please check. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm trying to find the library you are using. can you please link to the source and/or documentation?

Comment: Yes sure. The link is: https://jamaasmpp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi eliyashiv... Any advice?  Thanks

Comment: When are you calling `ReceiveSMS`? If it's not this, maybe it's to do with the host you are using.

Comment: I am calling the ReceiveSMS in the Main method. It is called when the console application starts.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Don't just silently throw the exception information away, it's important. Use break on all exceptions in the debugger, and you'll see when anything fails (if it does indeed fail).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot... I appreciate it..I am catching the exceptions and logging them, however the problem is that the event client_MessageReceived is not getting raised so it never throws any exception. Please let me know if I am raising the event correctly. I will really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your smpp gateway is configured to receive SMS. it should be configured in transceiver mode.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.